# Identifying and eliminating duplicate records in hive

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

Here is a sample from the data base I'm dealing with:

```
ID  Issue   Sub Issue   Creation Time            Solved Time
1   A        A1        01-05-2015 00:10:10       01-05-2015 10:20:00
2   B        B1        01-05-2015 00:10:55       01-05-2015 10:30:30
3   A        A2        01-05-2015 00:11:30       02-05-2015 08:10:45
4   A        A1        01-05-2015 00:14:45       01-05-2015 10:25:00
5   D        D4        02-05-2015 13:10:00          NULL
6   B        B1        02-05-2015 00:14:35          NULL
```

I want to identify IDs with the same issue,subissue and creation time<=5minutes as duplicate Ids and eliminate them.While eliminating, if both have a solved Timestamp or don't have a solved Timestamp, I can pick either.Else I pick the one with a value for Solved Timestamp.

Ex:1&4, 2&6 are duplicate Ids in this sample.I delete 1 and 6

Can someone help me with a Hive/SQL query for this.

Answer (score 0):

2 and 6 are not duplicates because there is different date, time difference is more than 23hrs.

I tested this solution on your sample data, it works fine:

`select id, issue, sub_issue, creation_time, solved_time
from 
( --calculate is_duplicate_flag for all rows
select case when ((unix_timestamp(next_creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')-unix_timestamp(creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'))/60 <=5) or 
                 ((unix_timestamp(creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')-unix_timestamp(prev_creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'))/60 <=5)
 then true else false end as is_duplicate_flag,
s.*
from
(select 
     t.*,
     lead(t.creation_time) 
         over(partition by t.issue, t.sub_issue order by  unix_timestamp(t.creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss')) as next_creation_time,
     lag(t.creation_time) 
         over(partition by t.issue, t.sub_issue order by  unix_timestamp(t.creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') ) as prev_creation_time,
     row_number() over(partition by  t.issue, t.sub_issue order by case when t.solved_time is not null then 1 else 2 end, unix_timestamp(t.creation_time,'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss') desc) as rn

  from 
  (select 1  as id, 'A' as issue,        'A1' as sub_issue,     '01-05-2015 00:10:10' as creation_time,    '01-05-2015 10:20:00' as solved_time from default.dual union all
   select 2  as id, 'B' as issue,        'B1' as sub_issue,     '01-05-2015 00:10:55' as creation_time,    '01-05-2015 10:30:30' as solved_time from default.dual union all
   select 3  as id, 'A' as issue,        'A2' as sub_issue,     '01-05-2015 00:11:30' as creation_time,    '02-05-2015 08:10:45' as solved_time from default.dual union all
   select 4  as id, 'A' as issue,        'A1' as sub_issue,     '01-05-2015 00:14:45' as creation_time,    '01-05-2015 10:25:00' as solved_time from default.dual union all
   select 5  as id, 'D' as issue,        'D4' as sub_issue,     '02-05-2015 13:10:00' as creation_time,       NULL               as solved_time from default.dual union all
   select 6  as id, 'B' as issue,        'B1' as sub_issue,     '02-05-2015 00:14:35' as creation_time,       NULL               as solved_time from default.dual 
)t
  ) s 
)s
where case when ! is_duplicate_flag then 1 else rn end =1
order by id`

Results:

`id      issue   sub_issue       creation_time   solved_time
  2       B       B1      01-05-2015 00:10:55     01-05-2015 10:30:30
  3       A       A2      01-05-2015 00:11:30     02-05-2015 08:10:45
  4       A       A1      01-05-2015 00:14:45     01-05-2015 10:25:00
  5       D       D4      02-05-2015 13:10:00     NULL
  6       B       B1      02-05-2015 00:14:35     NULL`